# How to place a Clickable Banner (redirects) on discord message channel?

Tags: discord

I'm trying to create a clickable banner on a discord room. Want to redirects users to a specific site address when them clicks on it. Please help!

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="Streamer", url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUndVC7rtFI", description="Canal do Streamer", color=0xff0000)
```

I need just a banner appearing and when users click on it, then they'll be redirected to a specific site or social web profile

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, one is to make the bot send an embed that has the link inside it. For example:

```
message.channel.send({embed:{
   title: 'Link',
   description: '[Click Here](www.yourlink.com)'
}});
```

The other option is to use webhooks which I don't know anything about, but you can search or ask other people for it.